# How do I get this very simple rspec test to pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm relatively new to Rails and RSpec. I spent a lot of time trying to understand the basics of RSpec, WebMock, stubs, and other related things I thought would help me, but I just can't get this test to pass.  I'm pretty sure this is a very simple and common test, but unfortunately I've now reached a point where I'm just randomly trying all options and hoping one would work by trial-and-error.

I have a very simple controller whose `index` action calls a service like this:

```
def index
  @some_var = @some_service.status # defined at rails-root/lib/services/SomeService.rb
  render :index
end
```

Of course, if I want to test this action, I would not want to make an actual service call. But I want to make sure @some_var is being set right. Therefore, I'm trying to write this:

```
  describe 'GET index' do
    it 'should set some_var' do
      @some_service.stub!(:status).and_return("aloha")
      get :index
      assigns(:some_var).should == "aloha"
    end
  end
```

As some of you might have guessed already, this gives me

```
expected: "aloha"
got: nil (using ==)
```

I think I'm not stubbing the service correctly. Could some one please help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stub any instance variable in controller you can get it by:

```
controller.stub(:some_var).and_return('aloha')
```

To stub model instance better you could have:

```
SomeService.any_instance.stub(:status).and_return("aloha")
```

Comment: Thanks! I came close to this! One of the options I tried was SomeService.stub(:status) -- I missed any_instance.  Thanks, again.

Comment: BTW, is there some way I could have used the double() method here?

Comment: Yes.
http://blog.firsthand.ca/2011/01/rspec-double-mock-and-stub.html

http://blog.firsthand.ca/2011/12/example-using-rspec-double-mock-and.html

Comment: Why use a mock? Shouldn't you configure your data to return 'aloha'? (Some rails test code spends more time testing mocks than production code.)

Comment: @Phlip I'm not sure what you mean by "Shouldn't you configure your data to return 'aloha'". I'm testing that my controller's index action properly calls a service and sets an instance variable. In the test I'm mocking that service here because I don't want to send a request on the wire. Could you explain your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Ah. I would have mocked the service at its lowest perceptible data layer; not just up at the surface. That kind of mock is okay too.